# Нет перевода текстов на индикаторах новичков

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, индикатор-новичка

Например, тут: [Долгий импорт бд MySQL centos 7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/871693/15479)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не долетело ещё или забыли?

Comment: Вот это «Не долетело ещё или забыли?» я не понял. Все переводы на энтузиастах держатся. Нет энтузиазма — нет и переводов :)

Comment: Заблокировал оба индикатора адблоком, чтобы не мешались, и нет проблем с переводом ;-)

Comment: @alexolut я думал, что перед такими апдейтами перевод заранее готовится (:

Comment: <здесь должна быть картинка с Гриффином>

Comment: @alexolut как же так-то D:

Comment: @Kromster, значит не у меня одного эти нововведения вызывают желание их скрыть :)

Comment: @gil9red там просят уже дать возможность убрать эту фигню (: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314511/260198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавили перевод и уже выкатили на сайт.